# WORD VBA to INSERT text after a list

Tags: vba, ms-word

At the end of our a Word2010 document we've a numbered list of 6 items. We would like to add a text, say, `End of Document` at the end of that document using `VBA`. But when I try the following code it always add a new list item (item 7) to the list with that text as shown in image below. **NOTE**: We don't have control over the document. So the last line of the document is always item number 6 of the list and when a user runs VBA code the code is supposed to add last line at the end of the document as `End of document.` And this line should not be the last item of the list.:

```
Sub test()

Dim oList As List

Set oList = ActiveDocument.Lists(1)
oList.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
oDoc.Content.InsertAfter "End of Document";

End Sub
```

**Snapshot of the list at the End of a document**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to insert at the end of the document, you dont even need to find the list, this should do:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content
    .InsertParagraphAfter
    With .Paragraphs(.Paragraphs.Count).Range
        .InsertAfter "End of Document"
        .Style = wdStyleNormal
    End With
End With
```